# Issue with loading view and web service synchronous call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am using iPhone to get data from my web service.
Because I wan't to display loading view while getting data I invoke web service synchronous.
I have button which navigate to table view (that get data from ws):

```
Loading *loading = [[Loading alloc]init];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:loading.view];

TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES]; 
[loading.view removeFromSuperview];
```

And I call web service in viewDidLoad of my view.

```
webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error]; 

NSString *xml= [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] 
                                        length:[webData length] 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
// Parse XML etc.
```

I have tried to add loading view before I call web service (in viewDidLoad) but still doesn't work.
Any idea how to display loading view?

Comment: are you sure you want to fetch the data synchronously? normally you'd want to do it asynchronously (so the app doesn't stall while it waits for the data communications to finish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the web service asynchronously. By doing it synchronously, you are blocking the main (UI) thread & it can't finish loading your view or make it appear (or animate things on the loading view), etc.

Comment: I was wrong. I thought that I need sync call. Calling it asynchronous fix the problem.